# Problem compiling face_recognition (procrob_functional)

Tags: ros, compile, face-recognition, boost, libboost

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi Ros users,

I would like to use face_recognition (procrob_functional) but I have got an error while compiling :

/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/Fclient.dir/src/face_rec_client.o: undefined reference to symbol 'vtable for boost::detail::thread_data_base'
/usr/bin/ld: note: 'vtable for boost::detail::thread_data_base' is defined in DSO /usr/lib/libboost_thread.so.1.46.1 so try adding it to the linker command line
/usr/lib/libboost_thread.so.1.46.1: could not read symbols: Invalid operation
collect2: ld a retourné 1 code d'état d'exécution
make[3]: *** [../bin/Fclient] Erreur 1

Any help welcome.

Thanks in advance

Christophe

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/35679/problem-compiling-face_recognition-(procrob_functional)/) by [Christophe](https://answers.ros.org/users/2344/christophe/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2012-06-04

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I encountered the same problem today and just followed the answer tor proposed. I want to clarify the answer for newbies like me

> rosbuild_link_boost(Fserver thread)

> rosbuild_link_boost(Fclient thread)

add these two lines after this one

> rosbuild_add_executable(Fclient
> src/face_rec_client.cpp)

---

Originally posted by [yigit](https://answers.ros.org/users/2389/yigit/) with karma: 796 on 2012-07-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3